# Changing a previous Workflow Approval Status for a *NEW* Workflow

Tags: ecl

I have a number of items (Components, Templates) that have a workflow Approval status (from another vendors' past workings with Workflow) that is less than that required to Publish to LIVE.

I can only see three ways of getting the list of items that have a latest version that does not have the minimum status.

1. Publish page by page and react to the Publish error telling me which item is stopping the publish (in that cycle of publishing ... i.e. it's often a number of items) *With the need to then add this item into a workflow, and force it through to attain the minimal approval status this is proving to be far far too painful*
2. Run a SQL query against a backup of specific data to generate a list of all items that require updating. Use the resulting IDs to **manually** generate the XML content for the workflow bundles (*`<item>`  WebDAV/ID in `<items>` node*). **Manually** Paste XML into Workflow Bundle in each publication level
3. As 2 but code to create bundle (and push through workflow)

I'm pushing for 3 with 2 as a fall back.

***Has anyone tried this?*** ...

Is this the start of ***the SQL***? I'm not sure where to go with this in that I need the @THE_ITEM to be dynamically iterated through each item ID in the table

```
DECLARE @THE_ITEM INT
SET @THE_ITEM = 6195
SELECT * FROM [TRIDION_CM].[dbo].[ITEMS]
WHERE ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = @THE_ITEM AND
    VERSION = (
        SELECT MAX(VERSION) AS MAXVERSION 
        FROM [TRIDION_CM].[dbo].[ITEMS]
        WHERE ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = @THE_ITEM
        AND APPROVAL_STATUS_ID <> 4
        )
```

From the output here I can easily concatenate the results into the necessary XML (or could use the API to grab each item in and and it into a bundle created in the correct context for pushing through workflow).

Any pointers / assistance / *answers* would be fantastic!

## UPDATE

### Final SQL used

*this was used and the result was reconstructed to provide the relevant `<items>`*

```
DECLARE @APP_STATUS_ID INT
SET @APP_STATUS_ID = 4
SELECT ID, PUBLICATION_ID, ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, APPROVAL_STATUS_ID, [VERSION], ITEM_TYPE, TITLE
FROM [TRIDION_CM].[dbo].[ITEMS] i1
/* just get from a subset - being the last version of each item */
WHERE i1.id=
    (   SELECT TOP 1 i2.id 
        FROM [TRIDION_CM].[dbo].[ITEMS] i2 
        WHERE i2.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=i1.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID ORDER BY [VERSION] DESC
    )  
    /* ignore items that already have the required 'live' approval status */
    AND ( i1.APPROVAL_STATUS_ID != @APP_STATUS_ID OR (i1.APPROVAL_STATUS_ID IS NULL))
    /* ignore items we're not workflowing */
    AND ( i1.ITEM_TYPE != 8 AND i1.ITEM_TYPE != 1024 AND i1.ITEM_TYPE != 2048  )
ORDER BY PUBLICATION_ID, ITEM_REFERENCE_ID
```

Comment: on reflection - posting a question with regards any interaction with the database is ill-advised. I've spoken directly with Paul who answered the question and he's in agreement.

Comment: We are speaking with support to resolve this issue as it's confirmed there's nothing in the APT to help us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate through each ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, and retrieve the one that has the highest VERSION. A fairly straightforward way to do that is:

```
SELECT i1.* FROM ITEMS i1
WHERE i1.ID=
(
    SELECT TOP 1 i2.ID 
    FROM ITEMS i2 
    WHERE i2.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=i1.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID 
    ORDER BY VERSION DESC
)
ORDER BY ITEM_REFERENCE_ID;
```

The inner query pulls the unique ID for each ITEM_REFERENCE_ID that has the max VERSION, builds a list of those ITEMS in the outer query, and returns that.